# Bash - create zip by finding files

Tags: bash, zip

I want to create bash script that find `*.mp4` and `zip` it.

I use this:

```
#!/bin/sh
zip -r $(find . -name '*.mp4').zip $(find "/home/ehsan/Desktop" -name '*.pdf')
```

but not work and get this error:

```
zip error: Zip file structure invalid (./Bank_Mellat_v3.2_hassas-computer.com/Help.pdf)
```

Comment: In your question you say you want to zip .mp4 files but in your sample zip command you are using .pdf. Which is it? Also, are you trying to: a) .zip each individual file separately (a .zip per file) or b) add every file to a single .zip?

Comment: edit question !. and i want to create each file to own zip. example: a.mp4 -> a.zip

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Zipping all files in one archive

You can zip all files with a basename matching *.mp4 found under the current directory into a single archive with the following command:

```
zip my_mp4_archive.zip $(find . -name "*.mp4")
```

## Zipping each file in an archive of its own

The following script will zip each file individually, in the same directory as the file itself is stored.

```
files=$(find . -name "*.mp4")

for f in $files; do
  echo "Compressing $f"
  (cd $(dirname $f) && zip $(basename $f.zip) $(basename $f))
done
```

Comment: tanx for helping. but i want to create each mp4 to zip. example: a.mp4 to a.zip and b.mp4 to b.zip

Comment: Alright, please take a look at my updated answer.

Comment: For the record, I don't think zipping mp4 files will decrease their file size much at all, because they are already highly compressed.

Comment: Doesn't works with spaces in the filename. I would give you a -1, but this makes no sense, as you are a rep 1 user.

Comment: Well then, I'm sure you can figure that out in your own. Good luck!

Comment: @A.B. Please don't use votes for punishment. I fixed the command for you, it will work for all filenames unless they contain newlines. In which case you should probably fix the filename instead...

Answer (score 3):

`zip` alone can do this. Also note that `zip`-ing the `mp4` files is inefficient as it won't give you any advantage as far as space is concerned as it is already in the compressed MPEG4 format.

To find all the `.mp4` files recursively starting from current directory and save them as `files.zip` :

```
zip files.zip -r . -i '*.mp4'
```

- `-r` denotes recursive operation
- `-i '*.mp4` specifies the only pattern we are interested in

**EDIT :**

After reading your comments it seems you want to find each `.mp4` file and create the `zip` of that file only and also want to do this for all `.mp4` files recursively. If that so :

```
find . -type f -name '*.mp4' -exec bash -c 'zip "${1%.mp4}".zip "$1"' _ {} \;
```

This will find all `.mp4` files recursively staring from current directory and `zip` them each separately. So `foo.mp4` will be `zip`-ped as `foo.zip`.
Again you won't get any compression advantage.

Comment: +1 Good answer, but I have a question. It's bad to use `find . -type f -name '*.mp4' -exec bash -c 'zip "${1%.mp4}".zip "$0"' {} \;` instead?

Comment: @A.B. You need `${0%.mp4}`, i know its a typo :) ..in this case it wont make any difference with `$0` but imagine a regular case that you want to get all the arguments with `$@`, as `$0` is not shown and `bash -c` starts arguments with `0` so yeah huge issue..

Answer (score -1):

Use this to compress all `.mp4` files in the base directory and it's sub directories.

```
$ zip test.zip `find . -name \*.mp4 -print | tr "\n" " "`
```

**Explanation**:

To compress file `zip file-name.zip path1 path2...`

To get all file paths having `.mp4` extension in base directory and all it's subdirectory use `find`:

```
find . -name \*.mp4 -print
```

To list all the output in one line separated by `space` like we require in our `zip` command pipe through `tr "\n" " "`

Putting everything together:

```
$ zip test.zip `find . -name \*.mp4 -print | tr "\n" " "`
```

**Update**
After reading OP's comment:

Simply iterate through all the found `.mp4` file's pathnames
eg:

```
for p in `find . -name \*.mp4 -print`                                                                                                           
do
    zip $p.zip $p
done
```

If your filename contains a space character, you case us `tr` to replace `space` with `backslash space`

Eg: Use `$p | tr ' ' "\' '"` instead of `$p`.

Comment: tanx for helping. but i want to create each mp4 to zip. example: a.mp4 to a.zip and b.mp4 to b.zip

Comment: -1 Doesn't works with spaces in the filename. And don't use `\`…\``, use `$(…)` instead

Comment: @Ehsan updated answer.