# Bash - Copy all .jar files to current directory from subfolders

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have folder named datahub and it has 15 folders and more than 20 subfolder which holds .jar files. I wanted to find all .jar files from subfolders and copy back to my current directory.

I am referring [Bash - create zip by finding files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/655649/bash-create-zip-by-finding-files) but this is copying subfolders as well, but i wanted to copy only .jar's to my current directory or to create one directory and copy to it.

Thanks in Advance for your help
Venkat

Comment: What happens if more than one file has the same name?

Comment: All the .jar names are unique not same at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Terminal and navigate to your source directory.

```
find ./ -name "*.jar" -print0 | xargs -0 cp -t "Destination"
```

This only works if the file names are unique and are not already inside the Destination folder.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming all file names are unique, you can use something like (from datahub directory):

```
find . -name "*.jar" -exec cp {} /path/to/targetFolder \;
```

where /path/to/targetFolder is the directory where all jar files will be copied.

Comment: 1 - Please warn that destination directory must not be a subdir of the `find` search directory -- 2 - In case of filenames with spaces... use `cp '{}' ...`

Comment: @cmak.fr quoting is not necessary for the case of whitespace - see [How does 'find -exec' pass file names with spaces?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/243095/how-does-find-exec-pass-file-names-with-spaces)

Comment: @cmak.fr In addition to what steeldriver said, note that `find` doesn't see the difference between `'{}'` and `{}`. The shell removes the quotes before passing the argument to `find` (and the quotes are unnecessary).

Comment: @steeldriver and eliah-kagan : thank you i  learned something today

Comment: @cmak.fr if you want to go even further down the rabbit hole see [GNU find and masking the {} for some shells - which?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8647/gnu-find-and-masking-the-for-some-shells-which)

Comment: @Abhishek Nair, your script is working fine, but how can i overwrite if i have files with same name?

Comment: @Venkat If you've file name conflicts, how do you suggest to specify which file to keep? There may be one or more name conflicts for each file, which one should take priority? cp allows certain arguments like -b or - - backup you may find worth looking if you want to consider avoiding overwrite.

Comment: @abhishek Nair, is there a way we can exclude files while executing find command?

Comment: Thanks all for your quick help.

Comment: @Venkat See this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/397307/how-to-ignore-certain-filenames-using-find) which suggests excluding options to use with find.

Comment: Thanks a lot Abhishek for all your help